# MSSQL: Transpose-Pivot table without aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, aggregate, transpose

> I need some help about MS SQL Transpose. I tried many pivot codes but they didn't help on my data.
>   This is my data. 
>   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzMXC.png)

I want to traspose(pivot) it without aggregate. Data should be like this,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3ZDV.png)

I tried the the following code;

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
        SELECT
        dm
        ,max(hucre) as mxhucre
        FROM #dene
        group by dm 
        ) as pTablom
PIVOT
(
        max(mxhucre)
        FOR dm IN (
        [1000_TEKİRDAĞ TM]
        ,[10000_TEKIRDAG OB1]
        ,[10100_YAĞCI DM]
))AS Pvt
```

but it gets,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHEUM.png)

this is not the data what I want. Most of values has gone

If I do not use aggrate (max-min.. etc) the code does not work.

Please help

Comment: *"I want to traspose(pivot) it without aggregate"* Not really possible as SQL Server PIVOT requires still some kind off aggregate function.

Comment: using aggregate function data does not come true. the result is only one row data

Comment: You should be providing create table structure with example data and expected results (no images).. as two people made very sound educated geusses into solving this

Comment: I did not show my tables in this page. thats why I import pictures. @Raymond Nijland

Answer (score 6):

use conditional aggregation

```
SELECT 
    max(case when dm='1000_TEKİRDAĞ TM' then hucre end) as '1000_TEKİRDAĞ TM'
    max(case when dm='10000_TEKIRDAG OB1'then hucre end) as '10000_TEKIRDAG OB1',
    max(case when dm='10100_YAĞCI DM  H04_T10' then hucre end) as '10100_YAĞCI DM  H04_T10'
FROM #dene
group by dm
```

Comment: i would choose this anny at time of the week over SQL Server PIVOT because this reads more easy, syntax is more easy to work with and it is portable between most RDBMS systems so +1

Comment: @RaymondNijland . . . This does not produce the desired results -- so I'm baffled by the upvotes.  Clearly, only one of the columns can have a non-`NULL` value for each row, because of the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: 1000_TekirdagTM               10000_TekirdagOB1                        10100_YagliDM
H15_31_50_KUBLAJ        NULL                                         NULL
NULL                                H12_KOMPANZASYON ÇiKiŞi NULL
NULL                                NULL                                         H04_T10             
This code does not work. The result is above. It gets only one row data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff this method is normally a pretty sound approach of pivotting, for better answers the topicstarter should update the question with create table structure and example data and expected results

Comment: @RaymondNijland . . . I'll let you run it so you can see what it really does.  I strongly encourage you to do that.

Comment: I would if i could @GordenLinoff but iam on holiday and i doubt SQL Server would run on Iphone

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use aggregation, like this:

```
with t as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by dm order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from <your table> t
     )
select max(case when dm = '1000_TEKİRDAĞ TM' then hucre end) as [1000_TEKİRDAĞ TM],
       max(case when dm = '10000_TEKIRDAG OB1' then hucre end) as [10000_TEKIRDAG OB1]
       max(case when dm = '10100_YAĞCI DM  H01_T10' then hucre end) as [10100_YAĞCI DM  H01_T10]
from t
group by seqnum;
```

You can do this without aggregation by using joins:

```
with t as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by dm order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from <your table> t
     )
select t1.hucre, t2.hucre, t3.hucre
from t t1 left join
     t t2
     on t2.seqnum = t1.seqnum
        t2.dm = '10000_TEKIRDAG OB1' left join
     t t3
     on t3.seqnum = t1.seqnum
        t3.dm = '10100_YAĞCI DM  H01_T10' left join
where t1.dm = '1000_TEKİRDAĞ TM';
```

Comment: But I have 652 dm. So it is difficult to write all of it one by one. Is there any way to dynamic to do this pivot? and First code doent work. One row data come.

Answer (score 0):

But I have 652 dm. So it is difficult to write all of it one by one